# Advantages of UI component libraries like Bootstrap-Vue and React-Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, vue.js, react-bootstrap

What are the benefits of using a framework like Bootstrap-Vue as opposed to regular bootstrap?

Is it in order to remove jQuery dependency?

Comment: If you head over to their [website](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) you'll find that it's a mashup of bootrap and vue all in one. Vue "is a progressive framework for building user interfaces." and I assume bootstrap is there to make it pretty.

Comment: @JNevill - I dont think its a mashup as both are imported separately into a project, both Vue and Bootstrap-Vue

Comment: If you're at this stage of your project, I suggest `quasar`: http://quasar-framework.org/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap-Vue is just a library of Vue components that are styled using Bootstrap. Looks like they were able to remove the jquery dependency (I would personally consider this a pro cause im not a big jquery fan, but in all reality this is pretty neutral). My reason for using it would just to be able to use useful, common UI components inside my vue application. If you are building all the components yourself then I would just use regular Bootstrap to style them.

Comment: Which would you use if you wanted to tweak the usual bootstrap styling?

Comment: I would use just the regular Bootstrap library. Bootstrap-Vue has built in vue components that it sounds like you dont need

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Vue removes jQuery from the picture and replaces it with Vue.

The benefit is as simple as it is integrated with Vue if you are using it already. No need to add the extra overhead of jQuery if you are already using Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Things like table, dropdown, tabs are harder to write yourself. All the components are battle tested implementations. It's a large component library, but you can import them individually to use as needed.